# UI elements in Gherkin Scenarios

Tags: tdd, bdd, gherkin, atdd

In our new project I'd like to try using Gherkin syntax as a way of creating specs with our customer that could then be used as the basis for BDD/TDD.

In my mind I'm not clear how to approach a scenario where, for example, a customer says that **when** a certain event happens **then** a UI element should be a certain colour. Should a Gherkin spec try to capture the change of colour in the **then** step? Does this mean that our tests (for example, in Jasmine) should check the colour of the UI element rather than the value of the variable that produces the change in the UI element?

Answer (score 1):

When using BDD you're usually writing the scenarios from the point of view of the user.  Therefore, it would make sense to write the assertion in your then step to be what the user sees, and in this example what the customer has asked for, i.e. that the UI element is the right colour.

Also, from a testing point of view it makes sense to automate the testing of something fully.  If your asserts are exactly what you would test if you were doing it manually then there isn't any need for someone to manually check it.